Application of the adjoint functor theorem to get the right adjoint of the forgetful functor from $\delta$-rings to rings (the Witt vectors)
I am studying $\delta$-rings and Witt vectors from [K] (the definition of $\delta$-ring is [K, 2.1.1]), and I am having trouble verifying that everything in Kedlaya's definition for the Witt vectors is in order. His definition is as follows: first, one defines the category $\mathbf{Ring}_\delta$ of $\delta$-rings whose objects are $\delta$-rings and whose morphisms are the ring homomorphisms $f:A\to B$ such that $f\circ\delta_A=\delta_B\circ f$. We then have a forgetful functor $\mathbf{Ring}_\delta\to\mathbf{Ring}$. Consider the following:
Theorem (Adjoint functor theorem, AFT, [SP, 0AHQ]). Let $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be a functor. Assume $\mathcal{C}$ is cocomplete and $F$ is cocontinuous, and that for every $y\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathcal{D})$ there is a set of pairs $(x_i,f_i)_{i\in I}$, where $x_i\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $f_i:F(x_i)\to y$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{D}$ such that for any pair $(x,f)$ where $x\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathcal{C})$, and $f:F(x)\to y$, there is an $i$ and a morphism $g:x\to x_i$ such that $f_i\circ F(g)=f$. Then $F$ has a right adjoint.
The hypothesis of the existence of such set of pairs $(x_i,f_i)_{i\in I}$ for each $y\in\operatorname{ob}(\mathcal{D})$ is called the “solution set condition” [R, Theorem 4.6.3].
Witt vectors are defined in [K, 2.4.5]: it is the functor $W$ which is right adjoint to $U:\mathbf{Ring}_\delta\to\mathbf{Ring}$. According to [K, 2.4.12], this right adjoint exists thanks to the adjoint functor theorem. However, I am having trouble checking the hypotheses of the theorem. I have already checked that $\mathbf{Ring}_\delta$ is
cocomplete and that $U$ is cocontinuous (hinted at the proof of [K, 2.4.3]). My problem is with the verification of the solution set condition. This is

[K, Exercise 2.13]. Show that the for the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Ring}_\delta\to\mathbf{Ring}$ the solution set condition for the right adjoint in the AFT is satisfied by taking all objects $x_i$ with $|x_i|\leq2^{\max\{|y|,\aleph_0\}}$.
Hint: Let $f:A\to B$ be a morphism in $\mathbf{Ring}$ with $A\in\mathbf{Ring}_\delta$. Define
$$
I=\{x\in A\mid \delta^m(x)\in\ker f,\;\forall m\geq 0\}.
$$
Then $\delta(I)\subset I$ and $I$ is an ideal of $A$, and the map
\begin{align*}
A/I&\to B\times B\times\cdots\\
x+I&\mapsto (f(x),f(\delta(x)),f(\delta^2(x)),...)\tag{1}\label{map}
\end{align*}
is injective.

(Note that \eqref{map} is just a map of sets.)
If I didn't get it wrong, it would actually suffice to consider all objects $x_i$ with $|x_i|\leq |y|^{\aleph_0}$, for if we showed the claims of the hint, then $A/I$ would be a $\delta$-ring [K, 2.4.2] and $|A/I|\leq|B^{\mathbb{N}}|=|B|^{\aleph_0}$ (why does Kedlaya write $|x_i|\leq 2^{\max\{|y|,\aleph_0\}}$?). Now, I managed to prove that $I$ is a $\delta$-stable ideal and that \eqref{map} is well-defined. However, I am having trouble checking it is injective. Injectivity of \eqref{map} amounts to the claim that for $x,y\in A$, if $\delta^n(x)-\delta^n(y)\in\ker f$ for all $n\geq 0$, then $\delta^n(x-y)\in\ker f$ for all $n\geq 0$. But why is this true? If one proceeds by induction, here is how one does the case $n=1$, i.e., $\delta(x-y)\in\ker f$ (thanks to მამუკა ჯიბლაძე for their help in the comments). Using [K, (2.3)], we have
$$
\delta(x-y)=\begin{cases}
\delta(x)-\delta(y)-\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{p}{p\choose i}x^i(-y)^{p-i},&p>2\\
\delta(x)-\delta(y)-y^2+xy,&p=2
\end{cases}
$$
We know $\delta(x)-\delta(y)\in\ker f$, but also $\ker f\ni -y^2+xy$ and $\ker f\ni \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{p}{p\choose i}x^i(-y)^{p-i}$ when $p>2$ (use that $f(x)=f(y)$ and that $\sum^{p-1}_{i=1}(-1)^{p-i}{p\choose i}=0$ when $p>2$ since ${p\choose i}={p\choose p-i}$). Thus $\delta(x-y)\in\ker f$. But how one does use this to prove the induction step? I don't see what one should do.

An apology of Kedlaya's definition (kind of as answer to the reasonable bewilderment of some people in the comments). Kedlaya's definition for the Witt vectors amounts to saying: we define the Witt vectors of a commutative ring $A$ to be a $\delta$-ring $W(A)$ along with a morphism of rings $W(A)\to A$ that is couniversal among morphisms of rings from $\delta$-rings to $A$. Explicitly: for any $\delta$-ring $B$ and any ring morphism $f:B\to A$, there is a unique $\delta$-ring morphism $B\to W(A)$ factoring $f$. Definitions in terms of universal properties are ubiquitous. The main drawback of such definitions is showing existence. In this regard, Kedlaya just invokes a formal tool (AFT) to tackle this (so did Joyal in [J], to which this definition via the right adjoint traces back). in [K, Ch. 3] the more usual definition for Witt vectors is recovered from the universal property [K, 3.2.1, 3.2.2]. See also this question.
References
[K] K. S. Kedlaya, Notes on Prismatic Cohomology https://kskedlaya.org/prismatic/frontmatter-1.html
[SP] The Stacks Project authors, The Stacks Project
[R] E. Riehl, Category Theory in Context
[J] A. Joyal, $\delta$-anneaux et vecteurs de Witt, C. R. Math. Rep. Acad. Sci. Canada 7 (1985), no. 3, 177–182

Have you tried to use (2.3) of the definition of $\delta$? It immediately gives the $n=1$ case, you can then proceed by induction.

It is not generally true that $|B^{\mathbb N}|=\max{|B|,\aleph_0}$. For example, this fails if $|B|=\aleph_\omega$.

Category of delta-rings is locally presentable (as any category of universal algebras), and functors between locally presentable categories have right adjoint iff they are cocontinuous. I wonder, what is the reason to try to use GAFT for this?..

@AndreasBlass : it also fails for $|B|=2$ or $\aleph_0$.

@AndreasBlass Okay, yeah. I was confusing cartesian product with disjoint sum when doing cardinal arithmetic. Thanks to Maxime Ramzi too. Why is it $|B^\mathbb{N}|\leq 2^{\max{|B|,\aleph_0}}$?

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე I edited the post explaining my problem with the case $n=1$.

Wow, this has to be the most complicated way of introducing the $p$-typical Witt vectors, and it's not for lack of competition!

@ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo From $f(x)=f(y)$ and $f\delta(x)=f\delta(y)$ you get $f\delta(x-y)=-\frac1pf(x)^p\sum_i\binom pi(-1)^{p-i}$ which is zero since $\binom pi=\binom p{p-i}$.

@darijgrinberg What would be the least complicated one that you know?

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე: The classical approach in Hazewinkel, Witt vectors (via the Dwork lemma) looks perfectly fine to me. Alternatively, use symmetric functions or power series to define big Witt vectors and then take a quotient.

$\def\a{\mathfrak{a}}
\def\ad{{\mathfrak{a}_\delta}}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}$I will include the proof of everything claimed in the hint of [K, Exercise 2.13].
$\underline{\text{Step 1}}\text{.}$ First we show $I$ is an ideal. To this aim, we first show that $\delta(\langle I\rangle)\subset\langle I\rangle$ (i.e., that the image under $\delta$ of an $A$-linear combination of elements of $I$ is again an $A$-linear combination of elements of $I$). Let $r\geq 0$. We show that for all $x_i\in A,y_i\in I$, $i=1,\dots,r$, we have $\delta(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i)\in\langle I\rangle$. By induction on $r$. The base case $r=1$ follows from [K, (2.2)]. Assume the result true for $r\geq 1$. Then, by [K, (2.3)]
\begin{gather}
\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r+1}x_iy_i\right)
=\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i+x_{r+1}y_{r+1}\right)\\
=\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i\right)
+\delta(x_{r+1}y_{r+1})
+\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{p}{p\choose j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i\right)^j(x_{r+1}y_{r+1})^{p-j},
\end{gather}
which is an $A$-linear combination of elements of $I$, by the induction hypothesis and the base case.


To show $I$ is an ideal we will prove that for all $r\geq 1$ and all $x_i\in A,y_i\in I$, $i=1,\dots,r$, we have $\delta^n(\sum_{i=1}^rx_iy_i)\in\ker f$ for all $n\geq 0$. By induction on $n$. The base case $n=0$ is clear, since $I\subset\ker f$. Suppose the result true for $n\geq 0$ and let's prove it for $n+1$. By induction on $r$. For $r=1$ we have
$$
\delta^{n+1}(xy)=\delta^n(\delta(xy))
=\delta^n(x^p\delta(y)+y^p\delta(x)+p\delta(x)\delta(y)),
$$
which is in $\ker f$ by the induction hypothesis on $n$. Assume the result true for $r\geq 1$ and let's show it for $r+1$. We have
\begin{gather}
\delta^{n+1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r+1}x_iy_i\right)
=\delta^n\left(\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i+x_{r+1}y_{r+1}\right)\right)\\
=\delta^n\left(\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i\right)
+\delta(x_{r+1}y_{r+1})
+\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{p}{p\choose j}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i\right)^j(x_{r+1}y_{r+1})^{p-j}\right),
\end{gather}
since both $\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_iy_i\right)$ and $\delta(x_{r+1}y_{r+1})$ are in $\langle I\rangle$ (shown earlier), the induction hypothesis on $n$ gives the result.
$\underline{\text{Step 2}}\text{.}$ Now we show the map \eqref{map} is well-defined, i.e., that $f(\delta^n(x+y))=f(\delta^n(x))$ for all $x\in A,y\in I$ and $n\geq 0$. For $n=0$ this is trivial since $I\subset\ker f$. Assume the result true for some $n\geq 0$. First note that from [K, (2.3)] and the fact that $I$ is a $\delta$-stable ideal it follows that $\delta(x+y)=\delta(x)+y'$, where $y'\in I$. Thus $f(\delta^{n+1}(x+y))=f(\delta^n(\delta(x+y))=f(\delta^n(\delta(x)+y'))=f(\delta^n(x))$, by the induction hypothesis.
$\underline{\text{Step 3}}\text{.}$ Finally, we show \eqref{map} is injective. We want to show:
\begin{gather}
\tag{P}\label{P}
\text{For all }x,y\in A\text{ such that }\delta^n(x)-\delta^n(y)\in\ker f\text{ for all }n\geq 0,\\\text{ it holds }\delta^n(x-y)\in\ker f\text{ for all }n\geq 0.
\end{gather}
We will prove something much stronger but more amenable to induction.
Assume $0\in\mathbb{N}$, and write $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}_f$ for the finitely supported sequences of natural numbers, i.e.,
$$
\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}_f
=\{n\in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}\mid\#\{\nu\in\mathbb{N}\mid n_\nu\neq 0\}<+\infty\}.
$$
Write $A_*=A\setminus\{0\}$. Given $K\in\mathbb{N}_f^\mathbb{N}$, $K=(k_0,k_1,\dots)$, and $c\in A_*^\mathbb{N}$, we denote $c^K=\prod_{\nu\geq 0} c_\nu^{k_\nu}$.
Definition. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal of the $\delta$-ring $A$.

We say that $a,b\in A^\mathbb{N}$ are $\mathfrak{a}_\delta$-congruent, and write $a\equiv b\Mod{\ad}$, if $\delta^m(a_\nu)-\delta^m(b_\nu)\in\mathfrak{a}$ for all $m\geq 0$ and all $\nu=0,1,\dots$
An element of $A$ is simply $\mathfrak{a}$-standard¹ if it is of the form
$$
\tag{2}\label{sta}
a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'}-a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'}
$$
where $a,b\in A_*^\mathbb{N}$ are $\mathfrak{a}_\delta$-congruent. (Note that minus a simply $\a$-standard element is a simply $\a$-standard element.)
An element of $A$ is $\mathfrak{a}$-standard¹ if it is an element of the non-unital subring generated by simply $\a$-standard elements. Equivalently, a $\a$-standard element is a sum of products of simply $\a$-standard elements.

Note that \eqref{sta} is $0$ modulo $\mathfrak{a}$ (since modulo $\a$ we have $a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'}=a^Ia^Jb^{I'}b^{J'}\equiv a^Ib^Ja^{I'}b^{J'}=a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'}$); thus $\mathfrak{a}$-standard elements are contained in $\mathfrak{a}$.
It is not easy to find subsets of a $\delta$-ring $A$ that are invariant under the action of $\delta$, for the $\delta$ operator is not additive nor multiplicative. Nonetheless:
Proposition. Let $A$ be a $\delta$-ring and $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$ be an ideal. The map $\delta^n$ preserves $\mathfrak{a}$-standard elements for all $n\geq 0$.
The Proposition proves \eqref{P} by considering \eqref{sta} and setting $a=(x,1,1,\dots)$, $b=(y,1,1,\dots)$, $I=J'=(0,0,\dots)$, $J=(1,0,0\dots)$, $I'=(0,1,0,0,\dots)$, and $\a=\ker f$.
Lemma. Let $a,b,c,d\in A^\mathbb{N}_*$ and suppose $a\equiv b$, $c\equiv d\Mod{\ad}$. Let $I,I',J,J',K,L\in\mathbb{N}_f^\mathbb{N}$. Then $c^K\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})-d^L\delta(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})$ is a sum of simply $\a$-standard elements.
Proof. Given integers $n_1,n_2,m_1,m_2$ we write $(n_1,n_2)\leq(m_1,m_2)$ iff $n_i\leq m_i$, $i=1,2$. Given $I_1,\dots,I_r\in\mathbb{N}_f^\mathbb{N}$, we write $\mu(I_1,\dots,I_r)=(m,n)$, where $m=\max(\max I_1,\dots,\max I_r)$ and $n\in\{1,\dots,r\}$ is the number of times that $m$ occurs in $(\max I_1,\dots,\max I_r)$. We prove the result by induction in $(m,n)=\mu(I,J,I',J')$. Case $(n,m)=(0,0)$ is obvious. Suppose $(m,n)>(0,0)$ and assume the result true whenever $\mu(I,J,I',J')<(m,n)$. Suppose $\mu(I,J,I',J')=(m,n)$. Then $\max(\max I,\max J')$ or $\max(\max J,\max I)$ equals $m$. We prove the case $\max(\max I,\max J')= m$ (the case $\max(\max J,\max I)= m$ is similar). Without loss of generality, we may assume $\max I=m$, and reordering $a$ and $I$ if necessary, we may suppose $i_0= m$. We now do induction on $k=$ the number of times that $m$ occurs in $I$. Suppose first $k=1$. Write $I_*=(i_0-1,i_1,i_2,\dots)$ (so that $\mu(I_*,J,I',J')<(m,n)$). Then $c^K\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})-d^L\delta(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})$ equals
\begin{gather}
\phantom{-}c^K
\left[
a_0^p\delta(a^{I_*+J}b^{I'+J'})
+(a^{I_*+J}b^{I'+J'})^p\delta(a_0)
+p\delta(a_0)\delta(a^{I_*+J}b^{I'+J'})
\right]\\
-d^L
\left[
a_0^p\delta(a^{I_*+I'}b^{J+J'})
+(a^{I_*+I'}b^{J+J'})^p\delta(a_0)
+p\delta(a_0)\delta(a^{I_*+I'}b^{J+J'})
\right].
\end{gather}
By induction hypothesis on $(m,n)$, this is a sum of simply $\a$-standard elements. The case “true for $k\geq 1$ implies true for $k+1$” is done the same way. $\square$
Proof of the Proposition. By induction, it suffices to prove the proposition for $n=1$. First we show that \eqref{sta} is mapped by $\delta$ to a simply $\a$-standard element. Assume first $p>2$. Then $\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'}-a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})$ equals
\begin{gather}
\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})-\delta(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})
-\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{p}{p\choose n}
(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})^n(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})^{p-n}\\
=\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})-\delta(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})
-\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{p}{p\choose n}(-1)^{p-n}
a^{pI+nJ+(p-n)I'}b^{nI'+(p-n)J+pJ'}\label{easy}\tag{3}
\end{gather}
The difference $\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})-\delta(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})$ is a sum of simply $\a$-standard elements by the Lemma. On the other hand, using that ${p\choose n}={p\choose p-n}$, the last sum in the RHS of \eqref{easy} equals
\begin{gather}
\tag{4}\label{sum}
\sum_{n=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\frac{1}{p}{p\choose n}
(a^{pI+nJ+(p-n)I'}b^{nI'+(p-n)J+pJ'}\\\qquad\qquad
-a^{pI+(p-n)J+nI'}b^{(p-n)I'+nJ+pJ'}).
\end{gather}
Since \eqref{sum} is a sum of simply $\a$-standard elements, so is \eqref{easy}. If $p=2$, then $\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'}-a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})$ equals
\begin{align*}
&\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})-\delta(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})
-(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})^2+a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'}a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'}\\
&=\delta(a^{I+J}b^{I'+J'})-\delta(a^{I+I'}b^{J+J'})
+a^{2I+I'+J}b^{I'+J+2J'}-a^{2I+2I'}b^{2J+2J'}.
\end{align*}
By the Lemma, the first difference is a sum of simply $\a$-standard elements. Note that the last difference is also simply $\a$-standard.
This finishes the proof that the image under $\delta$ of a simply $\a$-standard element is a sum of simply $\a$-standard elements.
Now we show $x=c_1\cdots c_s$ where each $c_n$ is simply $\a$-standard satisfies that $\delta(x)$ is $\a$-standard. By induction on $s$. Case $s=1$ is what we already showed. Assume the result true for $s\geq 1$ and let's prove it for $s+1$. We have
\begin{align*}
\delta(x)&=\delta(c_1\cdots c_{s+1})\\
&=(c_1\cdots c_s)^p\delta(c_{s+1})+c_{s+1}^p\delta(c_1\cdots c_s)
+p\delta(c_1\cdots c_s)\delta(c_{s+1})
\end{align*}
By induction hypothesis and the base case, this is a sum of $\a$-standard elements.
Finally, we show that for a generic $\a$-standard element $x=d_1+\cdots+d_r$, where $d_m=c_{m1}\cdots c_{ms_m}$ and each $c_{mn}$ is simply $\a$-standard, satisfies that $\delta(x)$ is $\a$-standard. By induction on $r$. Case $r=1$ has already been shown. On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\delta(x)
&=\delta(d_1+\cdots+d_{r+1})\\
&=\delta(d_1+\cdots +d_r)+\delta(d_{r+1})
-\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{p}{n\choose p}(d_1+\cdots+d_r)^nd_{r+1}^{p-n},
\end{align*}
which is a sum of $\a$-standard elements by induction hypothesis and the base case, and thus $\a$-standard.

¹I made up this terminology.
References
[K] K. S. Kedlaya, Notes on Prismatic Cohomology https://kskedlaya.org/prismatic/frontmatter-1.html

That's fine, except to use induction you should start with $\delta^{n+1}(x-y+z)$. But do you need this $z$? You can just use the $n=1$ case with $\delta^{n+1}(x-y)=\delta(\delta^n(x-y))$, as you already know that $\delta(I)\subset I$, no?

Also in 1. you probably mean "...an $A$-linear combination of elements of $I$ is again an $A$-linear combination of elements of $I$"?

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე I just corrected the typo with the $A$-linear combination of elements of $I$, thanks. You're right that my induction step is not the correct one. I don't understand your “you can just use the $n=1$ case with $\delta^{n+1}(x-y)=\delta(\delta^n(x-y))$, as you already know that $\delta(I)\subset I$.” How do you do it?

Sorry it seems I oversimplified. So the argument is still incomplete. You only have a proof that if $x,y\in I$ then $\delta(x-y)\in\ker(f)$.

I really wonder if Kedlaya intended this solution. It's too long and non-obvious for being regarded "an exercise."
